# Replace a character only in one special part of a string

Tags: php

When I've a string:

```
$string = 'word1="abc.3" word2="xyz.3"';
```

How can I replace the point with a comma after xyz in `xyz.3` and keep him after abc in `abc.3`?

Comment: What do you want to replace the point with? Also, what is the condition? Do you only want to replace the point when it is preceded by "xyz"? Or do you want to replace the point when it's not preceded by "abc"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've provided an example but not a description of when the content should be modified and when it should be kept the same. The solution might be simply:

```
str_replace("xyz.", "xyz", $input);
```

But if you explicitly want a more explicit match, say requiring a digit after the ful stop, then:

```
preg_replace("/xyz\.([0-9])+/", 'xyz\${1}', $input);
```

(not tested)

Comment: I tried to undestand the whole regex thing but I couldn't transfer

your example onto my code.

Could you please help me out with this one:


    preg_replace("/(\d)+\.(\d)+/", '[?help],[?help]', $string);


what shall the comma be surrounded with?

Answer (score 1):

something like (sorry i did this with javascript and didn't see the PHP tag).

```
var stringWithPoint = 'word1="abc.3" word2="xyz.3"';
var nopoint = stringWithPoint.replace('xyz.3', 'xyz3');
```

in php

```
$str = 'word1="abc.3" word2="xyz.3"';

echo str_replace('xyz.3', 'xyz3', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's string functions to remove the point (.).

```
str_replace(".", "", $word2);
```

Comment: I was just thinking about this, but the whole line is the string, they aren't variables...so I think.

Comment: if you know how many characters are in the string and the position of the second dot you can, replace the dot by using character counts. That might be a bit simpler than using complicated regex. i.e. $string[24] = ',';

Answer (score 1):

It depends what are the criteria for replace or not.
You could split string into parts (use explode or preg_split), then replace dot in some parts (eg. str_replace), next join them together (implode).

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
$string = 'word1="abc.3" word2="xyz.3"';
echo preg_replace('/\.([^.]+)$/', ',$1', $string);
```

**output:**

```
word1="abc.3" word2="xyz,3"
```